# Order by varchar stored as number giving wrong output

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying a simple select query but the output is totally wrong, mainly it's a Laravel project but I tried the SQL on phpMyAdmin and the error still the same

[image]

Comment: what's the datatype of `property_price`? `varchar`?

Comment: Which datatype has your column property_price? I guess it is char?

Comment: The best is to change the datatype in this way you can get issue while applying group function SUM, AVG and it will be a serious problem for the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the datatype of `property_price` is `VARCHAR`

```
SELECT * FROM properties ORDER BY property_price+0 ASC LIMIT 10;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM properties ORDER BY CAST(property_price AS UNSIGNED) ASC LIMIT 10;
```

**OR**

Change the datatype of `property_price` column to a numeric type.

Answer (score 0):

Check if property_price type is int.
Seems like varchar

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.